# frenchb/babel has no effect

Tags: captions, babel, linux, kile, french

As the title indicates, loading the frenchb/babel with `\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}` does not properly format my document for french typography and special characters ('é' is replaced with 'Ã©', etc...) and gives me the following warning :

```
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-french/frenchb.ldf:661:Please load the "caption" package(frenchb.ldf) AFTER babel/frenchb; reported on input line 661. Please loead the "caption" package(frenchb.ldf) AFTER babel/frenchb; reported
```

However, properly loading the `caption` package after babel does not solve the problem and does not make the warning disappear.

I am using Kile 2.1 on Linux.

EDIT : Here is the working example :

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper]{book}

%----- INVOCATION DES PACKAGES -----------------------------------------
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage{textcomp} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{verbatim} 
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{wrapfig} % Pour images
\usepackage{graphicx} % Pour images
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{subfig}
%\usepackage{slashbox} % CMD pour tableaux
\usepackage{array} % Pour tableaux
\usepackage{multirow} % Pour faire des fusions de colonne dans un tableau
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{tabularx} % Tableaux adaptés à la largeur de la page
%\usepackage{tikz} %Trik pour gantt
%\usepackage{pgfgantt} %CrÃ©ation du gantt
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} % Fait apparaitre la "liste des figures" et "liste des tableaux" dans la table des matiÃšres
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Pour les hauts et bas de pages
\usepackage{titlesec} %Pour modifier le format des chapitre
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
%\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{layout}
%\usepackage{showframe}% Montre les bords de champs
\frenchbsetup{ItemLabels=\textbf{*}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Test}

é, è, ê, ë, à, ù, ç

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Your example (MWE) works perfectly in my (french) computer. I think your OS does not support utf8 (or is misconfigured).

Answer (score 0):

there are two distinct problems here: input encoding, which may be solved with `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` and babel. The `caption` package is an outsider, it's just telling you to load it after babel so it knows in which language it should put the labels (like 'tableau 1.' instead of 'table 1.' etc).

Next question is, do you actually have troubles with babel? For example, do you have a "Table of contents" instead of "Table des matières"?

Comment: Using utf8 makes things slightly better as it makes 'é's appear properly. However other letters suchs as 'ç' or 'ù' are still not displayed when typed directly (although I am not sure that this is supposed to work for those letters). I already have "table des matières" and "table des figures" before changing to utf8.

Comment: that's weird, I don't have trouble with the cedilla ç nor with the accentuated ù. I use the packages
`\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`, `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, `\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}` (also `lmordern` and `aecompl` for fonts, but that's pretty much optional...)

Comment: et puis essaie avec seulement ces packages pour commencer, vis-à-vis de la liste longue comme le bras de ton exemple courant (il est potentiellement possible qu'un autre package interfère...)

Answer (score 0):

Is also a good idea to load "lmodern", so you can have accented characters in vectorial fonts. I load inputenc, fontenc, lmodern and babel, in that order. There are packages with conflicts with babel and even utf8, but that's not the case here (example "soul", pour souligner).